# ASP.NET Web Exception - Operation Timeout

Tags: asp.net, exception, web, timeout

I've got an ASPX page that populates a cell in an html table on a pre-existing Weather site. 
This aspx page reads an xml file and is IFRAMED into the table cell. It needs to refresh every 10 seconds to get the latest wind speed and direction. 
Unfortunately, the app encounters a time out exception (I presume - as stated in the event log).

Is this a session time out ? I've adjusted the application pool and web site in IIS to time out in 24 hrs (1440 minutes). This is not an issue, as the weather application is only used internally on our intranet, and only by a handful(3-6) of concurrent users.

What could be the cause ?

Here's the event log exception:

```
Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
Event Category: Web Event
Event ID:   1309
Date:       7/1/2014
Time:       1:22:08 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   mydomain.local
Description:
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 7/1/2014 1:22:08 PM 
Event time (UTC): 7/1/2014 5:22:08 PM 
Event ID: 5bf8561bd03c44cfae09560f02a4a495 
Event sequence: 168 
Event occurrence: 6 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/BMBWind-9-130487080560811444 
Trust level: Full 
Application Virtual Path: /BMBWind 
Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BMBWind\ 
Machine name: xxxx

Process information: 
Process ID: 7220 
Process name: w3wp.exe 
Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
Exception type: WebException 
Exception message: The operation has timed out 

Request information: 
Request URL: default.aspx 
Request path: /BMBWind/default.aspx 
User host address: 1.1.1.1 
User:  
Is authenticated: False 
Authentication Type:  
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Thread information: 
Thread ID: 3 
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
Is impersonating: False 
Stack trace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials)
at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, 
Boolean     includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Custom event details: 


For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Data:
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to include the code from default.aspx, but it looks like the timeout is coming from the "pre-existing Weather site" not from your intranet site. It is hard to tell for sure.  You may want to consider putting a try/catch block on your default.aspx to get more detailed information.  If it is in the event log, your site crashed and you don't get the most detail.  If you can confirm it is the other site, you can handle the timeouts with a couple retries and fall back to displaying "information temporarily unavailable".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Adam, 
the default.aspx is really simple, including a simple KeepAlive jquery script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"/> 
    <title></title>
    <meta id="MetaRefresh" http-equiv="refresh" content="21600;url=Default.aspx" runat="server" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {}
    </style>
</head>

<!-- This is a Session Keep Alive jquery script-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            setInterval(KeepSessionAlive, 10000);
        });

        function KeepSessionAlive() {
            $.post("/Shared/KeepSessionAlive.ashx", null, function () {
                $("#result").append("<p>Session is alive and kicking!<p/>");
            });
        }   
        </script>
    <div id="result"></div>
<!-- end keep alive-->

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="WeatherXML" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
        RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000"
        runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true">
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" CssClass="style1" Width="212px" 
        BackColor="Yellow" BorderColor="Yellow" BorderStyle="None" Columns="1" 
        Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Century" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black">    </asp:TextBox>
        <iframe ID="KeepAliveFrame" src="KeepSessionAlive.aspx" frameborder="0" width="0" height="0" runat="server"></iframe>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code to the parent "pre-existing Weather site": 
    
    
      
    Current Conditions at  ,  
        
        .style2
        {
            height: 21px;
            width: 156px;
        }
        .style3
        {
            height: 16px;0
            width: 135px;
        }
        .style4
        {
            width: 180px;
        }
        .style5
        {
            height: 16px;
            width: 180px;
        }
        
    
    
    **Current 
Weather Conditions at the Mid Hudson Bridge**

**As of:  06/12/14  8:38a**
    
    
        
            **Temperature:**
              **67.3°F**
            **Dewpoint:**
            **65.5°F**
      
    
        **Humidity:**
         **94%** 
        **Today's Rain:**
         **0.05 in**
     
     
        **Wind:**         
            
        **Storm Total:**    
        **0.05 in**
      
      
        **Barometer:**
          **29.733 in and Steady**
        **Current Rain Rate:**    
         **0.00 in/hr**

```
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if it is getting stuck at:

System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

so it is the weather site/service at fault. As mentioned by @Adam47 a try catch block will probably give you a bit more info and a way to handle timeouts. I hope this helps